# How to find all matches in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My expression is able to do for one occurence, but if multiple occurences are given it is capturing the whole part.

My regex is

```
[=:]\s*[\"\']?(.*=_ash)[\"\']?
```

I tried with both `regex.findall` and `search` 
I am getting the entire part when multiple occurences are there.

Do I need to set any flags for searching multiple occurences are is there a problem with my regex itself.

First three lines are working but

```
sample_string = 'asdfanksdfkjasdf_ash'

sample_str = "asdfasdfasdf_ash"

sample_st = assdfvb/23+sdf_ash

sample_s : 'assdfvb/23+sdf_ash'

sample = {'sample' : { 'hi' : 'asdfasdf+/asdf+_ash' , 'hello' : 'asdfasf+/asdf+v_ash' }}
```

I need only the value part here

Comment: Please be more clear in your question. Write what is the input what is the output and what is your expected output.

Comment: @nhahtdh It is not just for json, as my examples clearly tells it.

Comment: @Noname: Let me clarify my statement: If you have some way to separate JSON apart from other input, you should use a JSON parser to deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your pattern is the `.*`.

By default, the regex engine is greedy, `.*` consumes as much as it can. To change this behaviour, you can use a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). Adding the extra "**?**" in `.*?` makes it repeat as few as possible.

Also, you may want to make it fail in cases where a value doesn't end in `"_ash"`, checking for quotes in quoted text, or a space if it's not quoted:

**Regex:**

```
[=:]\s*(?:(["'])((?:(?!\1).)*_ash)\1|(\S*_ash)(?!\S))
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD3tV9/2)</kbd>

- `(["'])` captures the quote in group 1
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` matches any char except the quote captures in group 1
- `\1` matches the closing quote (the same used as opening quote)
- `\S*` with unquoted text, match anything except spaces
- `(?!\S)` check the value ends there

The values are captured in `.group(2)` if they're in quotes, or in `.group(3)` if unquoted.

**Code:**

```
#python 2.7.10
import re

text = """sample = {'sample' : { 'hi' : 'asdfasdf+/asdf+_ash' , 'hello' : 'asdfasf+/asdf+v_ash' }}"""
n = 0

pattern = re.compile( r'[=:]\s*(?:(["\'])((?:(?!\1).)*_ash)\1|(\S*_ash))')

#loop all matches
for match in pattern.finditer(text):
    n += 1
    print '\nMatch #%s:' % n

    #Show groups 2 and 3 captures
    for i in range(2,4):
        print 'Group %s - [%s:%s]:  %s' % (i, match.start(i), match.end(i), match.group(i))
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/e9mNwJ)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your regex to:

```
[=:]\s*['"]?([^\s\'\"=:]*?_ash)['"]?
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/hC1mT0/2)